# Does SourceTree 3.4.6 support Git-flow?

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

It seems I have missed something in settings (everything is by default, fresh installation) or ...
But I cannot use Git-flow in SourceTree (v 3.4.5).
Embedded Git version is 2.30.2. System Git version is 2.33.0.windows.2.

Any recommendations?

[image: here is screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when updating sourcetree to version 3.3.9 and I noticed that after the update it changed a git version setting to Embedded.
To fix it just go to Tools > Options > Git and in the Git Version section click on the SYSTEM button.

This way SourceTree will use the version of git installed on your PC.

[image]